# Rest web service to insert data into DB in java

Tags: java, rest

I am trying to insert data in to DB using rest web service in java with postman.
My Java code is as below :

Code in CourseService.java :

```
@POST
    @Path("/createUser")
     @Produces(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    @Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON)
    public String createUser(Course course) {
```

Code in Course.java :

```
package dto;

public class Course
{
    private int id;
    private String login;


    public String getLogin() {
        return login;
    }

    public void setLogin(String login) {
        this.login = login;
    }

    public int getId()
    {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id)
    {
        this.id = id;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString()
    {
        return "Course [id=" + id + ", name=" + login +"]";
    }

}
```

I am getting error as below when trying to post the data from postman :

> com.sun.jersey.spi.container.ContainerRequest getEntity SEVERE: A
>   message body reader for Java type, class dto.Course, and MIME media
>   type, application/json, was not found

Comment: Show what you are sending exactly

Comment: I am sending json object as below from postman body : {
"id":8,
"login":"xyz"
}

Comment: what are the headers?

Comment: In headers I have added "Content-Type" : "application/json" as key value pair

Answer (score 0):

You need to annotate you `Course` class with `@XmlRootElement`, as follows, so that `jersey` can serialize the input `json` to `Course`.

Also, make sure that you have [jersey-jars](https://jersey.github.io/download.html) in the classpath.

```
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement;

@XmlRootElement
public class Course { ... }
```

Comment: I tried adding this , but still getting the same error

Comment: Do you have `jersey` jars in your classpath?

Comment: I have following jersey jars in my classpath : jersy-client , jersey-core , jersey-json, jersey-server

Answer (score 0):

@XmlRootElement is an annotation that is commonly used when working with JAXB (JSR-222).  It's very purpose is to uniquely associate a root element with a class.  JAXB classes map to complex types, it is possible for your class to correspond to multiple root elements.

You may need to annotate your POJO Course Class with

```
package dto;
import javax.xml.bind.annotation.XmlRootElement

@XmlRootElement(name = "YourPreferredName")
public class Course
{
```